# List.contains(String) not working correctly

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, collections

Unable to understand the working of **List**.*contains()* method here,

**strAttributeList** - *List of selected attributes*
**subscriptionAttrList**- *List of all attributes*

I want to check that the each selected attribute in **strAttributeList** should be present in **subscriptionAttrList**, but I am unable to check that due unknown behavior of contains method.

**Demo List Values :**
strAttributeList= {"ALL"}
subscriptionAttrList = {"ALL", "NONE", "PO"}

```
for(String strAttrValue : strAttributeList){
    if(!subscriptionAttrList.contains(strAttrValue)) 
    return false;
};
```

**O/P:**

```
    subscriptionAttrList.contains(strAttrValue); //false
    subscriptionAttrList.contains(strAttrValue.toString); //false
    subscriptionAttrList.contains(""+strAttrValue+""); //false
    subscriptionAttrList.contains(""+strAttrValue.toString+""); //false
    subscriptionAttrList.contains("ALL"); //true
```

How all output is false and the 5th is true ?

Please provide the the correct way to compare values of 2 list as this is taking a lot of my time. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: what is o/p? ..

Comment: You are returning `false` after an element in `subscriptionAttrList` does not match the only element in `strAttributeList`. Try debugging your code.

Comment: There's nothing unknown about how `contains()` works. It works just as you expect, any bugs are in your own code.

Comment: what's in `strAttrValue` in O/P?

Comment: why not `subscriptionAttrList.containsAll(strAttributeList)`

Answer (score 0):

You returns false if any element of `strAttributeList` is not contained in `subscriptionAttrList`.
So as the two `List`s have one element in common but not all you are bound to return `false` :

```
strAttributeList= {"ALL"} 

subscriptionAttrList = {"ALL", "NONE", "PO"}
```

You should rather return `true` if an element is contained and after the loop return `false` as it means that no element matched :

```
for(String strAttrValue : strAttributeList){
    if(subscriptionAttrList.contains(strAttrValue)) 
       return true;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String strAttrValue : strAttributeList){
    if(!subscriptionAttrList.contains(strAttrValue)) 
    return false;
};
```

Your code finds an "ALL" at the beginning of the list but still iterates to the second element only to fail and return you false and hence you always get false. Its only when you have only 1 element and hence nothing to iterate further that you get a true.